# Recursion with for loops BASH

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop

I have yet another question. This code is for the rcS script in a Linux distro I'm making and for some reason occasionally it segfaults. About 85% of the time it works just fine and all is dandy. But then there is that 15% of the time when it segfaults on either creating a directory or doing the mount.

```
    # Find and mount all detected drives sda-sdm and partitions 0-10, you can change these by changing the values but odds are you won't have more than 26 USB drives plugged in or 10 partitions ;)
echo "  ${YELLOW}[ ${BLUE}*${YELLOW} ] Finding and mounting the program drive"
for DRIVE in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; do
    mkdir "/mnt/sd${DRIVE}/"
    mount "/dev/sd${DRIVE}" "/mnt/sd${DRIVE}/" 2> /dev/null
    if [ ! "${?}" = '0' ]; then
        rmdir "/mnt/sd${DRIVE}/"
    fi
    for PARTITION in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
        mkdir "/mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}"
        mount "/dev/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}" "/mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}/" 2> /dev/null
        if [ ! "${?}" = '0' ]; then
            rmdir "/mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}/"
        fi
        if [ -d /mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}/*/program-drive-${ARCH} ]; then
            if [ ! "${PROGRAM_DRIVE_FOUND}" = 'YES' ]; then
                PROGRAM_DRIVE_FOUND='YES'
                echo "${MESG} Found program drive on device sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION} mounted at /mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}"
                source /mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}/*/program-drive-${ARCH}/os_info
                rm "/etc/init.d/os_info"
                cp /mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}/*/program-drive-${ARCH}/os_info "/etc/init.d/os_info"

                echo "${MESG} Adding user ${USER}"
                /bin/adduser -s /bin/bash -G root -D "$USER"
                echo "${USER}:password" | /usr/sbin/chpasswd -m > /dev/null
                echo -e "${USER}\tALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

                mount -o loop /mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}/*/program-drive-${ARCH}/home "/home/${USER}/" 2> /dev/null
                rmdir "/home/${USER}/lost+found/" 2> /dev/null
                chmod 770 "/home/${USER}/"
                if [ ! "${?}" = '0' ]; then
                    echo "${MESG} Error mounting home on program drive! 'home' file gone or corrupt."
                    echo "${RED}SYSTEM BROKEN, PRESS ANY KEY TO SHUTDOWN:"
                    read -sn 1
                    poweroff
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: And my major issue here is as far as I can see its not doing extreme recursion that would normally make something segfault.

Comment: Is something actually segfaulting? The shell? The kernel? Or is the script just encountering an error and exiting?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm pretty sure its the script. The shell is just plain busybox SH. The thing is its not too specific, it just says "Segmentation fault". I actually changed the shell from BASH because with BASH it segfaulted about 60% of the time, of course though with BASH I used more BASHy code like "for blah in {1..10} blah" instead of listing out the numbers individually. I just have no idea what could be making it do this, I've been working on it for days.

Comment: Not enough information here to answer the question. Specifically it would be helpful to see the error (or segfault) you are getting. While debugging, you should probably take " 2> /dev/null" off the ends of commands so you have a chance to read any error output that's given to you.

Comment: You've been working on it for days yet you still have a 39-line script? Should have trimmed it down to <=five lines in the first hour.

Comment: @EtanReisner and btw the script doesn't quit when it segfaults, it just continues and normally boots just fine but if I want to publicly share it it can't have these kinds of errors.

Comment: @4ae1e1 yeah lol I normally make it smaller after I fix all the errors.

Comment: just as a debug idea, does putting a `sleep` in strategic places eliminate the error. It seems possible that the system can't keep up with all of this work and generates a Seg Fault to complain. But, your cmds are being run 1 after the other, so presumably they're completing before going on to the next step. Just an idea. Good luck.

Comment: @QuaDECH You should trim it down *to debug*, i.e., you should *hunt down where the bug is* instead of looking at a giant script and whining.

Comment: Here is the image of it segfaulting I have no idea why it does this and why it only does it sometimes ignore the mount messages, they come when I remove the "2> /dev/null" (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0gAxProEX_YzFpZmxCdk4xX2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @shellter I'll try that too

Comment: @4ae1e1 I just wanted to post the whole loop here just in case the problem was somewhere else. But it always does the segfault at either a mount or making one of the mount points.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the suggestions and putting up with me. shellter's suggestion ended up working. I put a sleep 0.05 right after the mount command and out of 15 tests it segfaulted on one. Now that I know exactly what the problem is I think I can go about fixing it on my own. But thanks again for the suggestions.

Comment: "its not doing extreme recursion that would normally make something segfault" -- it's not doing ANY recursion as far as I can see, though it's anybody's guess what `source /mnt/sd${DRIVE}${PARTITION}/*/program-drive-${ARCH}/os_info` might do.  Note, by the way, that that delegation presents an outrageous security risk.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Basically what that is is it has info about the user and stuff that it uses to generate it on boot. I know currently it is really insecure but I will make it encrypt the home container.